# Работа с куками в ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net, cookie

Добрый день.

Прошу пояснить, в чем ошибаюсь. Использую куки для хранения локали приложения. Как работать с куками посмтрел [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ie/ms178194.aspx). Создал веб-узел по стандартному шаблону, есть форма авторизации, редактирования профиля.

*Куки* ведут себя странно, они как будто для каждой страницы отдельно создаются, при переходе по страницам язык сбрасывается на русский, иногда значения полей стирается и файл становится пустым (смотрю в броузере)?

*Сессии* решил не использовать, т.к. время их жизни ограничено и куки, мне кажется, в данном случаи наиболее приемлимы или я ошибаюсь?

*Каждый раз*, при обновлении страницы (F5), язык меняется на противоположный, не пойму, почему?

1) Мастер-страница, при загрузке, инициализирует нужные куки:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim _cooke As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("culture")
        If _cooke Is Nothing Then _cooke = New HttpCookie("culture")
        If _cooke("UICulture") Is Nothing Or _cooke("Culture") Is Nothing Then
            _cooke("UICulture") = "ru"
            _cooke("Culture") = "ru-RU"
            _cooke.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(5)
            Response.Cookies.Add(_cooke)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

2) Для смены языка, там же, на мастер-странице имеется `LinkButton`:

```
Protected Sub ChangeLanguageButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ChangeLanguageButton.Click
    Dim _cooke As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("culture")
    If _cooke IsNot Nothing Then
        Select Case _cooke("UICulture")
            Case "ru"
                _cooke("UICulture") = "en"
                _cooke("Culture") = "en-US"
            Case "en"
                _cooke("UICulture") = "ru"
                _cooke("Culture") = "ru-RU"
            Case Else
        End Select
        Response.Cookies.Add(_cooke)
        'Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)     'правильно ли обновляю, нужно ли это делать???
    End If
End Sub
```

3) Для осуществления смены языка, все страницы наследуются не от `Page`, а от `MyBasePage`:

```
Public Class MyBasePage
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Overridable Sub InitializeCulture()
    If (Request.Browser.Cookies) Then
        Dim _cooke As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("culture")
        If _cooke IsNot Nothing Then
            If _cooke("UICulture") IsNot Nothing Then UICulture = _cooke("UICulture")
            If _cooke("Culture") IsNot Nothing Then UICulture = _cooke("Culture")
        End If
    End If
    MyBase.InitializeCulture()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Пробовал в разных броузерах, использование cookies разрешены.  
Web Dwveloper 2010 Express. .Net 4.0.

Comment: Странно, раскомментировал команду в строке    

     Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)     'правильно ли обновляю, нужно ли это делать???    

вроде работает, хотя раньше с этой командой пробовал, не работало. Сейчас тестирую на хосте.  
Все же прошу оценить, есть ли где улучшить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без "редиректа" ваш код не работает потому что событие установки культуры в жизненном цикле страницы генерируется на начальном этапе ДО события Init, в то время как событие нажатия ссылки ChangeLanguageButton_Click отработает уже ПОСЛЕ Load (как и все остальные пользовательские события) и поэтому после того, как вы сохраняете нужную культуру в куки она не применяется для страницы.

[Ссылка](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms178472.aspx) по поводу жизненного цикла страницы.

Comment: Спасибо, про жизненный цикл так и подозревал. На счет мего способа смены локали, что скажете?

Comment: Способ вполне рабочий и нормальный, единственное, что я бы вынес логику вычисления нужной культуры и работы с кукисами в отдельный класс, а из обработчиков событий только вызывал бы нужные методы.